Use reserved-memory and understand memremap() function
I try to implement my own Linux driver for a reserved-memory area. I following on this description: https://xilinx-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/A/pages/18841683/Linux+Reserved+Memory
The memory reservation already works as expected. Now I'm writing my Linux driver using the memremap() function in my probe function:
paddr = r.start;
vaddr = memremap(paddr, 4096, MEMREMAP_WB);
printk("Allocated reserved memory, vaddr: 0x%0X, paddr: 0x%0X\n", (u32)vaddr, paddr);
printk("Allocated reserved memory, paddr (2): 0x%0x\n", virt_to_phys(vaddr));

I try to understand the memremap() and virt_to_phys() since it is important for the driver to access the right physical adders at paddr. With the linese above, I would expect, that I have two times the same physical address paddr.
Unfortunately the output is:
[10370.743577] Allocated reserved memory, vaddr: 0xE0847000, paddr: 0x20000000
[10370.750564] Allocated reserved memory, paddr (2): 0x20847000

So there is an offset of 0x847000 bytes when try to get the physical address back from vaddr using virt_to_phys(). Where does this offset come from? I would expect that the driver reads and writes to 0x20000000 instead of 0x20847000.

I don't think virt_to_phys is intended for use on reserved memory, but the driver should already know the physical address without using virt_to_phys. The offset may be due to KASLR.
